# 2018 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

[The nomination phase of the moderator elections](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=nomination) was scheduled to end today. However, in order for the election to proceed, it is necessary to have at least one more candidate running than there are slots. This allows for there to be actual voting phases, so that the community can actually show that they support the candidates who are running. We will thus be extending the deadline for nominations for an additional seven days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless someone wants to take on the responsibility. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: I feel the word "nominate" is used where the word "volunteer" suits better.